# Can I use both SVN and WAMP?

Tags: svn

I have used SVN when SVN was installed on remote machine. I am impressed how it makes revisions. Now I want to install SVN on my local machine. I use WAMP on Windows XP and want to install SVN with WAMP.

After some research I have found that CollabNet SVN is the best SVN around. I have downloaded it and installed it but it screwed up my WAMP installation.

Do I need WAMP once I get SVN installed because it also has Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's just you and it's local, you could just install TortoiseSVN and use the "file://" method.  Then you don't need the subversion service even running.

Otherwise you could also check out VisualSVN, which is free for personal use (on Windows).

Comment: using visual SVN now. it works fine with WAMP SERVER. No need of changing anythng. Thanks